# Copy my.cnf file to Mysql Directory with Command Line

Tags: mysql, database, cp

I am trying to copy a new my.cnf to my mysql5 directory in the command line.  I have used:

```
cp my.cnf /opt/local/etc/mysql5
```

However when I execute the command, I get Permission Denied.

I am the directory where my.cnf resides.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried adding `sudo`?

Comment: do chmod 777 my.cnf !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy the file to root user's directory. You'll need to use `sudo`.

Try

```
$ sudo cp my.cnf /opt/local/etc/mysql5
```

Comment: Bingo.  I tried sudo, but must have been a mistake.  Do I need start and stop mysql for the new cnf to take affect?

Comment: @Hexana: Yes! You need to do that.